# I'm matching one of two characters on either side of a term with regex, but I want to ensure they're both the same character. How do I do this?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match one of two characters on either side of a term with regex, but I want to make sure that the first one I match is the one on the end as well, in other words they can't be mismatched.

These should work: `*word*`, `_word_`

This shouldn't: `*word_`

How do I ensure this?

Answer (score 3):

Use a back-reference:

```
([^a-zA-Z ])[a-zA-Z]+(\1)
```

The first group captures the non-letter/non-space char before a word.
The `\1` means "whatever is captured in group 1".

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/fuiMg3zgqa)

Comment: Correct in essence, but I think he's looking for `([*_])` as the first group.

Comment: @AlanMoore This regex matches what the OP wants and more. If it needs to be more specified for exactly `*` or `_` then it could be `([\*\_])[a-zA-Z]+(\1)`. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @WebWanderer: That's what I meant, we don't know if it's okay that the regex could match `@word@` and `&word&` in addition to `*word*` and `_word_`.  But the OP seems to have abandoned the question, so we may never get a ruling.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var string = '*word*';
/* try these as well:
var string = '_word_';
var string = '*word_';
*/

if (/(.)\w+(.)/.exec(string)[1] === /(.)\w+(.)/.exec(string)[2]) {

  alert('The characters at the beginning and end match.');

} else {

  alert('The characters at the beginning and end DO NOT match.');

}
```

By using the indexes on the `exec()` function, we can find the captured groups.  If the first captured group is them same as the second, then we have a match.